# Valgrind error invalid read of size 4

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, valgrind, allocation

```
void ChoreStack::add(int new_urgency_level, string new_job){
    for(int i = 0; i < length_; i++){
        Chore* temp_chore = chore_array_[i];
        if(temp_chore->level == new_urgency_level){
            temp_chore->joblist.append(new_job+"^");
        }
        chore_array_[i] = temp_chore;
        free(temp_chore);
    }
}
```

Hello, this is the part that Valgrind says "Invalid read of size 4". I have never learned anything related to memory allocation before. Could anyone please explain to me in details why there is a memory error and how to fix it? Thank you!

Here is my declaration:

```
class ChoreStack{
public:
    ChoreStack();
    ~ChoreStack();
    void initialize(int new_urgency_level);
    void add(int new_urgency_level, string new_chore);
    void erase(int erase_level);
    void print();
    void next();
int get_length();
private:
    struct Chore{
        int level;
        string joblist;
    };
    Chore** chore_array_;
    int length_;
    string* split_joblist(string joblist);
    int number_of_chores(string joblist);
};

ChoreStack::ChoreStack(): chore_array_(nullptr), length_(0){
}

ChoreStack::~ChoreStack(){
    delete[] chore_array_;
}

void ChoreStack::initialize(int new_urgency_level){
    delete[] chore_array_;
    chore_array_ = new Chore*[new_urgency_level];
    for(int i = 0; i < new_urgency_level; i++){
        Chore* temp_chore = new Chore;
        temp_chore->level = i+1;
        temp_chore->joblist = "";
        chore_array_[new_urgency_level-i-1] = temp_chore;
        delete temp_chore;
    }
    length_ = new_urgency_level;
    cout << "New priority list with levels 1-" << length_ << " initialized." << endl;
}
```

Here is the part related to ChoreStack::add() function in main():

```
int main(){
ChoreStack c;
string cmd_line;
string* cmd_ptr = new string[3];
bool initialized = false;
while(true){
    cout << "chores> ";
    getline(cin, cmd_line);
    int cmd_num = 0;
    if(cmd_line.find_first_not_of("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 ") != string::npos){
        cout << "Error: invalid input." << endl;
    } else {
        int begin_i = 0, space_occurence = 0;
        unsigned int i = 0;
        while(i <= cmd_line.length()){
            if(cmd_line[i] == ' ' || i == cmd_line.length()){
                space_occurence++;
                cmd_num++;
                if(space_occurence == 3){
                    cmd_ptr[cmd_num-1] = cmd_line.substr(begin_i);
                    break;
                } else {
                    cmd_ptr[cmd_num-1] = cmd_line.substr(begin_i, i - begin_i);
                }
                begin_i = i + 1;
            }
            i++;
        }
        string command = cmd_ptr[0];
        if(command == "init"){
            if(cmd_num == 1){
                cout << "Error: the number of priority levels is missing." << endl;
            } else if(cmd_num > 2){
                cout << "Error: too much input for initializing." << endl;
            } else {
                if(cmd_ptr[1].find_first_not_of("1234567890") != string::npos){
                    cout << "Error: the number of priority levels must be an integer larger than 0." << endl;
                } else if(stoi(cmd_ptr[1]) < 1){
                    cout << "Error: it is not possible to create a priority list with 0 or less levels." << endl;
                } else {
                    c.initialize(stoi(cmd_ptr[1]));
                    initialized = true;
                }
            }
        } else if(command == "add"){
            if(!initialized){
                cout << "Error: no priority list is initialized." << endl;
            } else {
                if(cmd_num == 1){
                    cout << "Error: priority level and chore description are missing." << endl;
                } else if(cmd_ptr[1].find_first_not_of("1234567890") != string::npos
                          || stoi(cmd_ptr[1])  < 1
                          || stoi(cmd_ptr[1]) > c.get_length()){
                    cout << "Error: priority level must be an integer between 1-3." << endl;
                } else if(cmd_num == 2){
                    cout << "Error: chore description is missing." << endl;
                } else {
                    c.add(stoi(cmd_ptr[1]), cmd_ptr[2]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the error message:

```
invalid read of size 4:
 1.ChoreStack::add(int,std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>)

 2.main

Address 0x5a9de70 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
 1. operator delete(void*)

 2. ChoreStack::initialize(int)

 3. main

Block was alloc'd at
 1. operator new(unsigned long)

 2. ChoreStack::initialize(int)

 3. main
```

and there are lot more errors in the same form of this one...

Comment: We'd probably need enough code to replicate the error. It would also help to see the full `valgrind` error message.

Comment: Hello, I am very sorry that I do not know how to copy error messages from QT creator. I am a newbee in programming......

Comment: Hello David, I just typed the error message by hand. May you please kindly help me analyze my code now? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: We'll probably need to see what `initialize` does then. This might be an access after free.

Comment: The code is added sir. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic access after free.

```
void ChoreStack::initialize(int new_urgency_level){
    delete[] chore_array_;
    chore_array_ = new Chore*[new_urgency_level];
    for(int i = 0; i < new_urgency_level; i++){
        Chore* temp_chore = new Chore;
        temp_chore->level = i+1;
        temp_chore->joblist = "";
        chore_array_[new_urgency_level-i-1] = temp_chore;
        delete temp_chore;
    }
```

Look closely at this code. You create a pointer called `temp_chore`. It points to an object you allocate with `new`. You then copy the value of `temp_chore` into `chore_array_`. So now the array has a pointer to the object you allocated with `new`.

But then you `delete` the object you allocated. So now, `chore_array_` has a pointer to an object you deleted. It is an error to attempt to dereference this pointer since the thing it points to no longer exists.

But then in `add`, we have:

```
    Chore* temp_chore = chore_array_[i];
    if(temp_chore->level == new_urgency_level){
```

So `temp_chore->level` is an attempt to access the `level` member of the object `temp_chore` points to. But you `delete`d that object.

```
        // Once you do this,
        chore_array_[new_urgency_level-i-1] = temp_chore;

        // this
        delete temp_chore;

        // does the same thing as this
        delete chore_array_[new_urgency_level-i-1];

        // because they're equal
```

You will find things much easier if you keep collections of values rather than collections of raw pointers.

Comment: Thank you, but sorry when I change it back to direct refering "chore_array_[i]->level = new_urgency_level-i;" the program doesn't even run anymore...

Comment: Until you fix all the bugs, your program will behave strangely and unpredictably.

Comment: Yeah indeed... I've been struggling till now... I managed to fix all errors besides one "invalid read of size 8" for no reason...

Comment: But thank you very much for taking time to help me solve part of my problem!!